# can an object a person ingests enter the appendix?

Tags: appendix

if one ingests (for example) a pebble in their food, which would be carried out through the rectum and later anus, passing through the colon in the feces, could it end up in the appendix?

I have interest in the function of the appendix organ. I looked for official references on this on the internet and have not found any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Foreign bodies are a rare cause of appendicitis. Sama and colleagues [report](https://jmedicalcasereports.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13256-016-0922-7) a case (2016. PMCID [4881009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4881009/)):

> [A] woman presented to our unit with a 1-week history of vague colicky lower abdominal pains occasionally radiating to her right iliac fossa (RIF), which progressively increased in intensity over the last 4 days and localized to her RIF. She also developed nausea and anorexia but reported no episodes of vomiting. She took self-prescribed doses of ibuprofen with no relief, prompting a consult at our health unit. ... An abdominal ultrasound scan was requested which revealed a thickened appendiceal wall and fluid collection around her RIF. ... Her appendix was found to be inflamed and an appendectomy was performed. No intraoperative complication occurred and her abdomen was closed in layers. Due to an unusual feel, we blindly dissected the resected appendix and found an incomplete piece of a rubbery material which was consistent with a condom